# How to update keywords metadata in DOC

Tags: java, apache-poi, doc

I am trying to update `keyword` in metadata of a DOC file. I've been able to update the `category` metadata with the code below but I don't see any methods for changing `keywords`

I'm using `poi:3.10-FINAL`

```
void updateProperties(String filepath) {
        POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filepath));
        DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
        DocumentSummaryInformation dsi;
        try
        {
            DocumentEntry dsiEntry = (DocumentEntry) dir.getEntry(DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
            DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(dsiEntry);
            PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
            dis.close();
            dsi = new DocumentSummaryInformation(ps);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            dsi = PropertySetFactory.newDocumentSummaryInformation();
        }
        dsi.setCategory("New Category set");


        dsi.write(dir, DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
        poifs.writeFilesystem(out);
        out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keywords are not stored on the `DocumentSummaryInformation`, they're stored on the other property stream, the `SummaryInformation`

If you look at the JavaDocs for [SummaryInformation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html), you'll see it has the method [setKeywords(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html#setKeywords%28java.lang.String%29) of which you search!